# Loading an xml file only once in spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

In spring, how would I go about loading an XML file once such that I can reference the file in my controller actions and not have to load it up again and again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a bean whose sole purpose is to read your XML file and has the desired accessor methods, and inject it into your controller.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring , all beans are initialized as Singleton unless specified . You could inject the properties from your XML file as follows

The xml file format for the properties is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="key1">Value 1</entry>
    <entry key="key2">Value 2</entry>
</properties>
```

you can use

```
 <context:property-placeholder 
 location="classpath:/com/myProject/spring_prop.xml" />
   <bean id="bean" class="org.MyBean">
     <property name="key1" value="${key1}" />
   </bean>
```

Or read the XML files in an @PostConstruct method via a bean as @Jens has mentioned .